# Delete a group of selected variables

Tags: r

This code

```
d <- 5
for(i in 1:10) { 
   nam <- paste("S", i, sep = "")
   assign(nam, rnorm(3)+d)
}
```

builds variables `A1, A2,A3...A10` changing variable name in a for loop. My question is: how do i delete all these variables (with only one instruction) from memory without touching the other environment variables? (I'm using RStudio)

Comment: I guess you meant `S1`, `S2` instead of `A1`, `A2` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to remove those variables, just use the same syntax with `paste` and as `paste` is vectorized it can create a vector of object names which can be fed into the `rm` with `list` argument

```
rm(list = paste0("S", 1:10))
```